# MapThread with List Manupulation

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax

I have the following three lists:

```
kr = {{8, 8, 19, 3, 3}, {8, 8, 21, 3, 3}, {8, 8, 23, 3, 3}};
Rk = {{8., 3, 4, 5, 6}, {8., 4, 5, 6, 7}, {8., 5, 6, 7, 8}};
qsum = {{320, 270, 120, 140, 170}, {320, 280, 120, 150, 190}, {320, 290, 120, 160, 210}};
```

When I use

```
MapThread[#1 + #2 + #3 &, {Take[#, {3, -2}] & /@ kr, Take[#, {4, -1}] & /@ Rk, Take[#, {3, -2}] & /@ qsum}]
```

It shows the output
    {{144., 149.}, {147., 160.}, {150., 171.}}

which is perfectly fine, but using the function `floExct` in the `MapThread` as

```
floExct[n_, ku_, qr_] := Min[100*ku, (2500*n) - qr];
MapThread[ floExct[#1, #2, #3] &, {Take[#, {3, -2}] & /@ kr, Take[#, {4, -1}] & /@ Rk, Take[#, {3, -2}] & /@ qsum}]
```

gives me

```
{500., 600., 700.}
```

instead of the format

```
{{a,b},{c,d},{e,f}};
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You are aware that the function Min returns a single scalar value?

Comment: I understand that the function `floExct` will return 1 value, but it should be evaluated 6 times and needs to give 6 values.

Comment: The dimensions of the list MapThread is being applied to is {3,3,2}, so you would expect only three results.

Comment: `Take[#, {3, -2}] & /@ kr`->`{{19, 3}, {21, 3}, {23, 3}}`, `Take[#, {4, -1}] & /@ Rk`->`{{5, 6}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}}` and 
`Take[#, {3, -2}] & /@ qsum`->`{{120, 140}, {120, 150}, {120, 160}}` so I would expect the result to be in the `{{a,b},{c,d},{e,f}}` format

Comment: Try this `MapThread[floExct, {Take[#, {3, -2}] & /@ kr, Take[#, {4, -1}] & /@ Rk, Take[#, {3, -2}] & /@ qsum}, 2]`

Comment: That worked..Thanks!!

Comment: @Aky, you could make your comment an answer, so that it could be accepted and we could upvote it. It'd definitely have my +1, as I actually didn't yet know about MapThread's levelspec argument.

Comment: @user402749 I started composing it as an answer, but then became undecided. I guess I'll post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was initially mentioned in the comments, you can use the levelspec argument of `MapThread` to get the behavior you were expecting, but you can also set your `floExct` function to have the `Listable` attribute. This is why `Plus` works well for your first example snippet.

```
In[11]:= floExct[n_, ku_, qr_] := Min[100*ku, (2500*n) - qr];
SetAttributes[floExct, Listable];
MapThread[
 floExct[#1, #2, #3] &, {Take[#, {3, -2}] & /@ kr, 
  Take[#, {4, -1}] & /@ Rk, Take[#, {3, -2}] & /@ qsum}]

Out[13]= {{500, 600}, {600, 700}, {700, 800}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the neat trick to make custom functions as `listable`.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it wouldn't hurt to add a bit of explanation here.

`Plus` is `Listable`, which is why `Plus[{a, b}, {c, d}]` evaluates to `{Plus[a, c], Plus[b, d]}` (it automatically threads over lists in its arguments). In fact, you did not need to use `MapThread` at all:

```
Plus[Take[#, {3, -2}] & /@ kr, Take[#, {4, -1}] & /@ Rk, 
 Take[#, {3, -2}] & /@ qsum] (* {{144, 149}, {147, 160}, {150, 171}} *)
```

On the other hand, `Min` flattens any lists in its arguments, eg. `Min[{a, b}, {c, d}]` evaluates to `Min[a, b, c, d]`, **not** `{Min[a, c], Min[b, d]}`

Now, generally speaking, `MapThread[func, {{p1, q1}, {p2, q2}}] == {func[p1, p2], func[q1, q2]}`

Consider that `p1`, `p2`, `q1` and `q2` could themselves be lists, eg.
`p1 = {a1, b1}, p2 = {a2, b2}, q1 = {m1, n1}, q2 = {m2, n2};`
The third argument of `MapThread` determines at which level of the list you want the threading to happen.

With the levelspec = 1 (default), `MapThread[func, {{p1, q1}, {p2, q2}}] == {func[{a1, b1}, {a2, b2}], func[{m1, n1}, {m2, n2}]}`, mentally replacing `func` with `Min` (and recalling its flattening behaviour) explains why the output isn't what you desire.

OTOH, `MapThread[func, {{p1, q1}, {p2, q2}}, 2]`, which is the same as
`MapThread[func, {{{a1, b1}, {m1, n1}}, {{a2, b2}, {m2, n2}}}, 2]`,  evaluates to `{{func[a1, a2], func[b1, b2]}, {func[m1, m2], func[n1, n2]}}`. If you mentally replace `func` with `Min` (or your `floExct`) you'll see this is the expression you want.

I'm afraid I haven't been able to express myself clearly (perhaps someone could polish it?), but hopefully the reader will be able to connect any missing links.

Comment: Got it...Thanks.